# NPM Custom URL Module From Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, package, npm

I'm trying to set a dependency in a package.json file to a remote beanstalk repository to have it included in a project.

Currently it's setup as the following:

```
{
  "name": "SOME_NAME",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "SOME_MODULE_NAME" : "git@xxx.beanstalkapp.com:/xxx.git#v0.0.1"
  }
}
```

This however returns the following npm error:

```
npm WARN package.json SOME_NAME@0.0.1 No README.md file found!
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/SOME_MODULE_NAME
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/SOME_MODULE_NAME
npm ERR! 404 'SOME_MODULE_NAME' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.
```

It seems to bypass the beanstalk url and falls back to finding a module within the global repo. Any thoughts / suggestions?

I've also tried utilizing the git+ssh:// style url to no avail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**See "[Git URLs as Dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies)"**:

> Git urls can be of the form:
>
> ```
> git://github.com/user/project.git#commit-ish
> git+ssh://user@hostname:project.git#commit-ish
> git+ssh://user@hostname/project.git#commit-ish
> git+http://user@hostname/project/blah.git#commit-ish
> git+https://user@hostname/project/blah.git#commit-ish
> ```
>
> The commit-ish can be any tag, sha, or branch which can be supplied as an argument to git checkout. The default is master.

Your url should be:

```
"git://xxx.beanstalkapp.com/xxx.git#v0.0.1"
```